# Necessary and sufficient condition for a $ 2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix to be correlation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-regression

How to prove this:

for a $ 2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix $A$, it represents a correlation matrix iff the diagonal entries  are one and the off-diagonal entries are less than one.

Comment: Did you try to apply the definition of the correlation matrix? What matrix did you obtain? Can you deduce something from that?

Comment: By definition of correlation matrix diagonal entries are one but what about off diagonals...

Comment: Can the off-diagonal elements be strictly greater than $1$ in absolute value? (Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz)

Comment: No, off diagonal elements can be less than or equal to 1.

Comment: Hence you've shown the direct part: a $2\times 2$ correlation matrix has $1$ on its diagonal and the off-diagonal elements belong to the interval $[-1,1]$. Now to the reverse part: for a given $c\in [-1,1]$ find two random variables $x$ and $y$ such that $corr(x,y)=c$.

Comment: My problem is with inequality, how it is less than 1

Comment: You can not say that they are strictly less than one. Take a correlation matrix for variables $(X,X)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree because of that only I think inequality problem is coming, so it should be less than or equal to 1, which can be shown even by considering determinant of the matrix as correlation matrix is positive semi-definite.